# How to download client-site a video with cURL / PHP?

Tags: php, curl

If the following PHP is runnig, I would like to download the file with `cURL on the client-site. It means, if one of my website visitor run's an action, which starts this PHP file, it should download the file on this PC.

I tried with different locations, but without any success. If I run my code, it does always download it on my WebSever, which is not this, what I want.

```
<?php
//The resource that we want to download.
$fileUrl = 'https://www.example.com/this-is-a-example-video';

//The path & filename to save to.
$saveTo = 'test.mp4';

//Open file handler.
$fp = fopen($saveTo, 'w+');

//If $fp is FALSE, something went wrong.
if($fp === false){
    throw new Exception('Could not open: ' . $saveTo);
}

//Create a cURL handle.
$ch = curl_init($fileUrl);

//Pass our file handle to cURL.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

//Timeout if the file doesn't download after 20 seconds.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

//Execute the request.
curl_exec($ch);

//If there was an error, throw an Exception
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
}

//Get the HTTP status code.
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

//Close the cURL handler.
curl_close($ch);

if($statusCode == 200){
    echo 'Downloaded!';
} else{
    echo "Status Code: " . $statusCode;
}
?>
```

How can I change the `cURL downloading process` to the `client-site`?

Comment: Why not just put the link to the file in the HTML?

Comment: PHP can't store anything on the users computer. You need to download it to the server and then send it to the user, or download it and stream the response to the user. Either way, it needs to go through the web server if you're using PHP. Alternatively, you could simply output the link and let the user access the link directly.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The URL is an remote URL which is not hosted on my Webserver. But this information doesn't care the client. If he would like to download it, he should click on a button, where the download starts. One special point, I would like to specify the filename, before downloading starts. Is that possible?

Comment: @obe because I want to specify the filename.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson `Alternatively, you could simply output the link and let the user access the link directly.` Do you have an example for this, for an remote URL (which is not from my domain)?

Answer (score 0):

PHP cannot run client-side.

You *could* use cURL to download data to the server (without saving it to a file) and then output that data to the client.

Don't do this:

> ```
> //Open file handler.
> $fp = fopen($saveTo, 'w+');
> ```

or this:

> ```
> //Pass our file handle to cURL.
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
> ```

Then capture the output:

> ```
> //Execute the request.
> curl_exec($ch);
> ```

Should be:

```
//Execute the request.
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Then you can:

```
echo $output;
```

… but make sure you set the `Content-Type` and consider setting the `Content-Length` response headers. You might also want `Content-Disposition`.

---

Under most circumstances, it would probably be better to simply send the browser to fetch the file directly instead of proxying it through the server.

```
$fileUrl = 'https://www.example.com/this-is-a-example-video';
header("Location: $fileUrl");
```

Comment: Thanks for anaswering. Well, from my side, it doesn't really have to be cURL if there is a simpler way. My aim is to do the downloading process on client-site on most efficient way. But what I dont want to is work with header. I tried it with headers, but unfortunatly I had the problem, that the dowloaded file was always 0 kilo byte, so some headers were missing. Thats why I am trying it with curl. But question: the last part of your comment, is this only 2 lines for downloading a URL or is it as additional of my of my own code?

Comment: One special note I should be allowed trough php or whatever, to specify the filename of the client-site downloaded file.